# AEG dishwasher not starting

Tags: dishwasher, troubleshooting

I have an AEG dishwasher (fsb42607z) that will not start.

This started a day ago. I set a program and close the door. About 2min later the door just opens. No sounds of even trying to pull water, drain, nothing. Just opens. When it does there is no sign of the lights flashing or anything. Just looks exactly as it did when I set the program

I have checked water pressure and that looks good. Checked pipes for kinks, nothing there. Stuck a snake camera down the sink hole to check for a blockage, clean as you like.

Booked an engineer but they won't arrive for another 2 weeks. AEG is starting to feel like a bad brand at this point. They didn't even bother troubleshooting with me. The manual does not state this scenario.

Any idea would be awesome. Cannot open the machine for warranty reasons. I just don't want to wait two weeks only to be told it was something silly.

Comment: Tried a forced empty pump cycle? often there is a button combination to do that. Or is there a reset combination?

Comment: One problem with one particular machine doesn't mean the company's entire product line is bad, nor does a delay in obtaining service - _every_ company is having a hard time with employees right now. It may be that it'll be _another_ 2 or more weeks to get repair parts because the places that make the parts are running behind, too.

Comment: The first thing a repair person will check is to make sure the **float/switch** in the bottom of the machine is not jammed on a fork or something.  It is there to measure the water level.

Comment: @FreeMan I have had the machine less than a year. I spent a lot of money on it. I think I can be allowed some frustration. If Aeg had explained the reason for the delay I would be more understanding. When I explained the issue and they told me 2weeks wait my first question was why so long. The lady said it just is. No explanation. So, I stand by my frustration, it is entirely justified.

Comment: @SolarMike Tried to force the drain cycle and nothing happened. No sound, nothing. Maybe the flood prevention switch Steve Wellens just mentioned could be the reason. Won't know till the engineer arrives. Thanks for trying guys

Comment: I know nothing of Aeg as a company, yet I understand that the _whole world_ is experience "supply chain issues". A simply look around _any_ shop shows a lack of product on the shelves and a lack of sales people willing to go to work (why should they when the gov't is paying them not to?). I don't discount your frustration with those facts, but they're a reasonable assumption to make at this point in time. Frankly I'm more frustrated by the world's situation that any one particular event. You, of course, can choose differently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case someone else comes across this. There was no issue with the machine, it had entered demo mode.

To deactivate it

press **ECO + Auto** for 5seconds

This just goes to show that AEG should have just debugged with me on the call. If they had done so we would not have had to wait 2 weeks and no engineer would have been called. It is also not in the manual. Multiple failures here AEG.

Comment: Wow... What a pain! Thanks for coming back to document the solution.